# I cannot up my vagrant+rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vagrant

I'm using Windows, and I want to use https://gorails.com/guides/using-vagrant-for-rails-development vagrant+rails

I followed every step in that link and created a lot of projects there, but after three months I got some issues.

```
 default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...        
 default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
```

[image]

In my vagrant i changed the host from 3000 to 5000 and run the vagrant perfectly and I changed to 3000.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: I had this issue once and the way I fixed it was to log into the VM from VirtualBox (vagrant/vagrant as username/password) and change the permission of .ssh/authorized_keys (`chmod 0600 .ssh/authorized_keys`), doing this while vagrant up is looping on the error, and it show success

Comment: i can't access to my vagrant because i type vagrant ssh and display:
 vagrant ssh
==> default: The machine you're attempting to SSH into is configured to use
==> default: password-based authentication. Vagrant can't script entering the
==> default: password for you. If you're prompted for a password, please enter
==> default: the same password you have configured in the Vagrantfile.
Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: I said to access the VM from VirtualBox not through vagrant to check the status

Comment: inccorrect password my password is not vagrant